# how to get the sha value after push image to docker repo

Tags: docker, github

Now I am implement a docker ci in github actions, first step build the docker image and push to remote repo like this:

```
- name: Build image push to aliyun
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
  with:
    registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
    username: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }}
    tag_with_sha: true
    repository: reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post
    path: 'dolphin-post'
```

after pushed to remote repo, the next step I want to update my kubernetes cluster app using this newest image. I want do it like this:

```
- name: deploy to cluster
  uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
  with: # defaults to latest kubectl binary version
    config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
    command: set image --record deployment/my-app container=${{ github.repository }}:${{ github.sha }}
- name: verify deployment
  uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
  with:
    config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
    version: v1.21.0 # specify kubectl binary version explicitly
    command: rollout status deployment/my-app
```

the `github.sha` represent the newest image sha code. But now I did not know how to get the `github.sha` value. Should I set into environment variable? How to set into environment variable? Where and How should I set the `github.sha` value?

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
- name: Build image push to aliyun
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
  with:
    registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
    username: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }}
    tags: ${{ github.sha }}
    repository: reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post
    path: 'dolphin-post'

- name: deploy to cluster
  uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
  with: # defaults to latest kubectl binary version
    config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
    command: set image --record deployment/dolphin-post-service dolphin-post-service=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/dolphin-post:${{ github.sha }} -n reddwarf-pro
```